# Where do I find search terms for shopping campaigns in Google Ads data transfer service tables

Tags: google-bigquery, google-ads-api, google-cloud-data-transfer

We are migrating our app to use the Google Ads transfer service tables rather than the Google AdWords transfer service tables in BigQuery. We are having trouble finding the search terms that used to be in the table `SearchQueryStats` for "SHOPPING" campaign types. It seems like it only contains "SEARCH" campaign types. Does anyone know if they moved to a different table or if the data is just not available in the BigQuery datasets?